# Finding the probability of destroying the target

Tags: statistics

Hi I am trying to do the following problem.

Consider a guidance system which is designed to deliver a bomb to a target site, which we denote $(x_0,y_0)$. As with all things, the guidance system that we consider is imperfect and will deliver the bomb to a point (x,y), where the joint PDF  of this random vector, given the point of target, is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y|x_0,y_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}exp\Big\{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2}-\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{2}\Big\}$$ where both X and Y are measured in feet. If a particular target, located at the point (3,2), will be destroyed if a bomb is delivered within r=2 feet of it, what is the probability that the target will be destroyed if 10 bombs are fired at it?

Now so far my thinking is that taking $(x_0,y_0)=(3,2)$ I can write the PDF as $$f_{X,Y}(x,y|x_0,y_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}exp\Big\{-\frac{(x-3)^2}{2}-\frac{(y-2)^2}{2}\Big\}$$ which can also be written as $$f(r)=\frac{1}{2\pi}exp\Big\{-\frac{1}{2}r^2\Big\}$$

Now if I integrate the above function from 0 to 2 I would have the required probability. I am confused with the number 10, what should I do with it. Also I am not sure whether I am at all in the right path or not?
I would highly appreciate that if you could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you just integrate the function from 0 to 2, you are just computing the probability of hitting it with a single shot. We know that if you make more attempts, the probability should increase.

Let's assume that each shot is indeed independent. Of course in practice, you are going to adjust your aim based on previous attempts.

$Pr(\text{ destroying a target in 10 shots})\\
=1-Pr(\text{ not destroying the target in any of the 10 shots})\\
=1-Pr(\text{ not destroying the target in a single shot})^{10} \\
=1-(1-Pr(\text{ destroying the target in a single shot}))^{10}$